# Angular 2+ ActivationEnd event callback called multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm seeing one subscription to `router.events` yield three calls per route change to the callback function, and each reports `instanceof event` as `ActivationEnd`.

```
console.log('This code runs only once, at site initialization.');
router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
    if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
        console.log('This should only log once per route change, but logs three times.');
    };
});
```

I found [this thread](https://github.com/ngrx/router-store/issues/29) on Github, which seems related, but I'm having a hard time believing this is still an issue...

I'm using Angular 5 (5.2.10).

UPDATE: It appears that this event is getting fired once for each route segment... Checking documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that I should be using NavigationEnd instead of ActivationEnd to achieve the desired result. I should have known that. I think my eyes failed to notice the difference.

Comment: But still using NavigationEnd does not solve the problem for me. As it is being called twice.
Did you found any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Check whether it is initiating multiple times?

if execute twice or multiple times this event,

```
router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
```

then this will get fired multiple times.

```
if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
    console.log('This should only log once per route change, but logs three times.');
};
```

So please make it

```
    if (!alreadyexist){

    router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {

      if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {

        console.log('This should only log once per route change, but logs three times.');

      };
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinctUntilChanged` to solve this. Only triggered if URLs are not the same.

```js
let prevUrl = ''
this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((e) => e instanceof ActivationEnd),
    distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => this.router.url === prevUrl),
    tap(()=>prevUrl = this.router.url),
).subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
        console.log('This should only log once per route change, if url is the same ');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is with specific params, in the next example I'm retriving the guid param and the subscription trigger only if that param change in value, using ActivationEnd events.

```
constructor(private router: Router)

    this.router.events.pipe(
        filter((e) => e instanceof ActivationEnd),
        map((e) => e instanceof ActivationEnd && e.snapshot.params),
        distinctUntilKeyChanged("guid"),
        map(({ guid }) => guid)
     ).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).